# Starting at Max/Min Value Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set my scroll bar to start at the minimum/maximum value and at mid point of my max and min value..

So it looks like this:

I have two range of values from (minimum) 1 to (maximum) 2. I have created a scroll bar that allows me to range between 1 to 2. So every time, I click my scroll bar, it increases from 1.1, 1.2,1.3 .. 2.0. However, I would like for my scroll bar to start at either the maximum or at 1.5 every time I open my spreadsheet.

I have this code:

```
Private Sub scollbarStart_Change()
    Range("E2") = CSng(scrollbarStart.Value/100)
End Sub

Private Sub scrollbarStart_Scroll()
    scrollbarStart_Change
End Sub 

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) 
    If Not (Intersect(Target,Range("E2:E2")) Is Nothing Then

    scrollbarStart.Min = Value(Range("C2")) *100
    scrollbarStart.Max = Value(Range("F2")) *100
    scrollbarStart_Change

    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas how this works?

Comment: This code runs in an event. What event? What is scrollbarStart_Change? Post the missing code or explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question... Is this okay?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Worksheet_Activate() to set the value of the cell that stores the scroll bar min value. I can't tell from your code which cell that is.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("A1") = 15  ' or whatever number you want in there.
End Sub
```